# R Cran ldei: error in svd(V2, nu = 0, nv = unsolvable) : a dimension is zero

Tags: r, svd

I am quite new to R-Cran. I would like to solve a  linear inverse model with constrains. I am using the ldei-function  in the limSolve package.
Here are my linear system and constrains:

A x X = C

G x X >=H, with  G=I and H=0. (Basically: X>=0)

where:

A in a 2x2 matrix;

X (nrow=2, ncol=n) is the unknown-vector-(matrix);

C (nrow=2, ncol=n) is the constant-known vector-(matrix).

The matrix G is the identity matrix and H is a vector-(matrix) with zero values.

The constrain X>=0 needs to be satisfied as X represents concentrations of nitrogen dioxide and ozone in outdoor air, and they cannot be negative.

Here is my r-code, I assume n=10:

```
library(limSolve)

A <- matrix(data = NA, nrow=2,ncol=2)
A[1,c(1:2)] <- c(-3.956946e-05,-1.558643e-05)
A[2,c(1:2)] <- c(-8.785099e-05, 1.540414e-04)

ctmp1 <- c(-3.000286e-04,-0.0003545647,-0.0002958569,-0.000356863,-0.0003602479,-0.0004177914,-0.0004280350,-0.0003890670,-0.0004984785,-0.0005695379) 
ctmp2 <- c(-6.462205e-05,-0.0007740174,-0.0006427914,-0.001056369,-0.0009569179,-0.0008562010,-0.0005402486,-0.0005043381,-0.0006366220,-0.0009332219)
inC <- rbind(ctmp1,ctmp2)
C <- matrix(data=inC, nrow=2, ncol=10)              

G <- matrix(ncol=2,nrow=2,data= c(1,0,0,1))
inH <- rbind(rep(0., length.out=10),rep(0., length.out=10))
H <- matrix(data=inH, nrow=2, ncol=10)

# I am aware I need to use the apply-family instead of do loops-- this is my work in progress--.. 
for (i in 1:10){ 
                print(i)
                E <- A
                FF <- c(C[1,i],C[2,i])
                GG <- G
                HH <- H[,i]
                res <-ldei(E,FF,GG,HH)
                print(res$X)
                }

### Here the output:
[1] 1
[1] 6.326385 3.188475
[1] 2
[1] 8.93305028 0.06985077
[1] 3
[1] 7.44753875 0.07454004
[1] 4
   Error in svd(V2, nu = 0, nv = unsolvable) : a dimension is zero
```

I would be very grateful for any hint to solve the issue:

"***Error in svd(V2, nu = 0, nv = unsolvable) : a dimension is zero***"

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, welcome to R!

If you want to see the code for a function you can just type the name of the function without paretheses and R shows the code.  So, for svd, we can see that it gives the error you see when there aren't enough dimensions... which means the as.matrix(x) hasn't given an object with dimensions, which means its input x must be not quite as expected.

You can edit these functions too... for debugging purposes.  I normally just paste into a text editor, edit and paste back into R.

```
svd = function (x, nu = min(n, p), nv = min(n, p), LINPACK = FALSE) 
{
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    if (any(!is.finite(x))) 
        stop("infinite or missing values in 'x'")
    dx <- dim(x)
    n <- dx[1L]
    p <- dx[2L]
    if (!n || !p) { 
        print("x")
        print(x)
        print("dx")
        print(dx)
        print("dx1L")
        print (dx[1L])
        print("dx2L")
        print(dx[2L])
        stop("a dimension is zero");}
    La.res <- La.svd(x, nu, nv)
    res <- list(d = La.res$d)
    if (nu) 
        res$u <- La.res$u
    if (nv) {
        if (is.complex(x)) 
            res$v <- Conj(t(La.res$vt))
        else res$v <- t(La.res$vt)
    }
    res
}
```

I've made it print out the values of interest...

```
[1] "x"

[1,]
[2,]
[1] "dx"
[1] 2 0
[1] "dx1L"
[1] 2
[1] "dx2L"
[1] 0
```

As suspected, the input has no data...

I pulled the same trick in ldei to get the values of E and V2 (which are the x given to svd)  I won't put that code here as it's a big much.

The upshot of it is that `rnd` in

```
V2 <- V2 %*% rnd
```

is width 0 because

```
unsolvable <- Nx - solvable
...
rnd <- matrix(data = runif(Nx * unsolvable), nrow = Nx, 
        ncol = unsolvable)
```

and both Nx and solvable are equal to 2!

The reason it even reaches that part of the code is that no all of CC are bigger than -tol... in this case:

```
[1] "CC"
      [,1]
[1,]  9.570040
[2,] -1.399828
[1] "-tol"
[1] -1.490116e-08
```

Ultimately, the difference in CC is because of the value of F.

So my guess is that the case where FF = c(C[1,4],C[2,4]) produces an error that is not handled by the function.

Sorry I can't do better!

Answer (score 0):

Following the tips Jimi provided, which I am really grateful for, I contacted directly the maintainer. Here below are her suggestions to "skip" the error. They worked for my case.

"The error means that the system is not solvable with ldei, and the function does not catch the error. What you can do is:

```
for (i in 1:10){
            print(i)
            E <- A
            FF <- c(C[1,i],C[2,i])
            GG <- G
            HH <- H[,i]
            res <-try(ldei(E,FF,GG,HH))
            if (! class(res)%in% "try-error")
              print(res$X)
            }
```

Therefore, when  class(res)%in% "try-error", then it is not solvable (likely at the requested precision)"